# Overseas Teaching of ABRSM Piano Students

Tags: piano, exam

I am Australia based. Can I teach online to my Singapore based student; and will I then be allowed to teach and enrol him in ABRSM Piano exams from Australia that he will complete in Singapore? Does ABRSM mind if the piano teacher and student do not reside in the same country?

Answer (score 5):

I have registered students in ABRSM exams, and the registration process is location agnostic. There's no restriction on where the teacher and student are with respect to each other. And, should some problem arise, the student or the student's parent can register themselves.

Answer (score 4):

No exam board is interested in who does the teaching. Consider self-taught, effectively with no 'teacher'. And on-line courses could be taken anywhere in the world. As long as the exam fee is paid, the candidate turns up at the appropriate time/place, with instrument if needed, (and grade V theory held for 6,7 and 8) job done!